# Unable to share data between functions in Javascript after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

First I declare an array to store my returned data and a variable to hold the raw JSON data for testing purposes.

```
<script>
  var XMLdataResult;
  var arrayOfShelters = [];
```

I have successfully called in an array of objects from mySQL using a php page using an AJAX request.  During the AJAX request I am able to display my data via alert() and validate that my data is indeed reaching its destination.

```
//RETRIEVE MARKER DATA 
    //Import JSON data into a variable.
    var dataXMLhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    dataXMLhttp.open("GET", "./js/returnData.php", true);
    dataXMLhttp.send();
    dataXMLhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

      if(dataXMLhttp.readyState == 4 && dataXMLhttp.status == 200){
      //the response is stored in a variable
        var XMLdataResult = dataXMLhttp.responseText;

        var arrayOfShelters = eval(XMLdataResult);

    //Data successfully output here
        window.alert("Inside AJAX Call" + arrayOfShelters);
    //function called
        setShelters();
      }
    }
```

At this point I have tried to directly output my array and my raw data again with no success.

```
        window.alert(arrayOfShelters);
```

Appears to return an empty string.

```
        window.alert("setShelters()" + XMLdataResult);
```

returns undefined.

It follows reason that my following functions are also unable to access any data.

```
function setShelters(){
    if(arrayOfShelters){
      //the response is stored in a variable
      for(i=0; i < arrayOfShelters.length; i++){
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(arrayOfShelters[i].lat, arrayOfShelters[i].lng);
        var shelterOptions = {
          position : myLatLng,
          map : mapCanvas,
          description : arrayOfShelters[i].title,
          icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
        };
      //create marker
        this ['shelter' + i] = new google.maps.Marker(shelterOptions);
      }
      window.alert("setShelters()" + XMLdataResult);
      window.alert("setShelters()" + arrayOfShelters);
    }
  }
</script>
```

I am probably missing something very basic being as Im still a green horn.  Possible conflicts I hypothesize, a previous ajax call further up the script could be causing problems?  My understanding of data flow and functions could be the issue.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: inside your ajax response you are doing var arrayOfShelters again, but you already declared your arrayOfShelters variable before. you don't need to do "var" again, doing that you're declaring a new variable inside your ajax response. and the same with XMLdataResult

Comment: So simple it hurts.  Feel free to post it as an answer and Ill accept it.  @JVLobo

Comment: great @DMrFrost I'll do it

Comment: I thought you were going to accept mine, since I was the first who helped you, hehe. but that's ok...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really simple mistake:

When you say `var arrayOfShelters = eval(XMLdataResult);`, you are creating a new local variable.

You have to say `arrayOfShelters = eval(XMLdataResult);`

The `window.alert("Inside AJAX Call" + arrayOfShelters);` is getting the array for the local variable, so that's why it's working there, but not anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that inside your ajax response you are doing:
`var arrayOfShelters`, but you already declared your `arrayOfShelters` variable before, so you don't need to declare the "var" again.

By doing that you're declaring a new variable inside your ajax response. and the same with happen with `XMLdataResult`.